# Edit object before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this stored in a variable (`cbsaList`):

```
["Dothan, AL", "Gadsden, AL", "Birmingham-Hoover, AL"]
```

I want to append a comma separated and spaced list to an existing div, so I tried this:

```
$("#geo_data").append(cbsaList);
```

But I get:

```
Dothan, ALGadsden, ALBirmingham-Hoover, AL
```

instead of (what I'd like):

```
Dothan, AL, Gadsden, AL, Birmingham-Hoover, AL
```

How can I prep an object like this (which may have more or less than 3 items) to append as I need?

Answer (score 2):

use join().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```
cbsaList.join(', ')
```

and then append the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join()` to turn an array in to a string, delimited as you require. Try this:

```js
var cbsaList = [ "Dothan, AL", "Gadsden, AL", "Birmingham-Hoover, AL" ]
$("#geo_data").append(cbsaList.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="geo_data"></div>
```